# How to keep tabs from collapsing or show hamburger when window resizes?

Tags: php, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a WAMP website and I'm using bootstrap. I have read other answers regarding the same issue, which suggested using a fixed width on my container and overriding bootstrap styling - but I just can't get it.

So I have tabs that collapse when I resize the window (at about 960px to 760px). Then anything smaller than 760px shows the hamburger nav bar. I would like to either keep the tabs from collapsing until the hamburger shows, or just show the hamburger when the tabs would have collapsed. However, I can't get it to either to work. Here is my relevant code (style.css and header.php):

```css
/* Reset CSS*/

html, body, header, footer, hgroup, nav, article, section, figure, figcaption, h1, h2, h3, ul, li, body, div, p, img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  /* Aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of the parent element. This is default*/
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* Override */

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a.active,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
  color: #50c4e9; /* Blue */
}

.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #50c4e9; /* Blue */
  background-color: transparent;
}   

.navbar-header {
  background-color: #fff;
}

footer,
footer p {
  color: #777
}

/* Content */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans';
  src: url('../fonts/gill-sans-mt-light.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans Regular';
  src: url('../fonts/gill-sans-mt-regular/GIL.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: bold;
}


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', Calibri, sans-serif;
  color: #777; /* Grey #756c6c */
  margin: 0;
}

.active {
  color: #50c4e9; /* Blue */
}

/* Responsive image */
@media(max-width:991px) {
    #splash-preload {
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
   /* Take off border from nav when phone size */
   .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
     color: #777;
     border-bottom: 0;
   }
}

/* If JS is disabled - default size */
img {
  height: 530px;
  width: 1110px;
}

.my-icon {
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- navbar-brand is hidden on larger screens, but visible when the menu is collapsed -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">m design</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <?php
                    echo '<li><a ' .(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'awards.php' ? ' class="active"' : ''). ' href="awards.php">awards & recognition</a></li>';
                    echo '<li><a ' . (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'work.php' ? ' class="active"' : '') . ' href="work.php">work</a></li>';
                    echo '<li><a ' . (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'about.php' ? ' class="active"' : '') . ' href="about.php">about</a></li>';
                    echo '<li><a ' . (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'contact.php' ? ' class="active"' : '') . ' href="contact.php">contact</a></li>';
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

(And my CSS files are in the order of: bootstrap CSS, then business-casual bootstrap CSS, followed by my own CSS)

[Image of tabs in expanded window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bx4E.png)

[Image of (undesirable) collapsing tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8UIG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since StackOverflow doesn't support PHP, I'm going to take a wild guess and assume your `li` are in `display: inline-block;` mode and not `float: left` mode.  If they're `float: left` you should be setting the following rules on `.navbar-collapse`:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  float: none !important;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

As for preventing them from wrapping, it's as simple as adding one CSS rule to the same block.  That's `white-space: nowrap` which prevents the document flow from wrapping elements that would scroll off the edge of their container.  In this case, the container is your `body` element.  Your new block would look like this:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  float: none !important;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Of course, if your elements are already in `display: inline-block` mode with no float, the block is just:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I investigated the li for float and display properties, and I found that .navbar-nav>li was set to float:left, while .nav>li was set to display:block from the min bootstrap CSS. So I overrode .navbar-nav>li to float: none and .nav>li to have display:inline-block. Then I put white-space:nowrap for .navbar-collapse in my media query for the tablet size, and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you!  Don't forget to mark this as the answer if this solved your problem so future SO users that have the same problem can easily find it.

Comment: I tried to upvote but my reputation isn't good enough for it to publicly display it.

Comment: Not upvote.  There should be a checkbox under the up and down votes.  Just click that.